# Ruby on Rails heroku and dedicated server deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, dedicated-server

I am wondering if I can use heroku's free service for my app ? If not, How much would it cost to host at heroku? What would be the tech specs for a small dedicated server for this purpose?  What is cheaper? The app is a  bookkeeping and invoicing office solution for a maximum of 6 concurrent users.

Comment: Yes you can use it, the downside is that heroku is sending free instances to sleep after 30 min and they must sleep for 6 hours of 24, or just buy the hobby plan which is 7$.

Comment: Thank you Alex I will be using the free edition as the workload is done on a 9-5 m-f schedule.